# Redirect on success and show error on failure

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have implemented a controller to create new users. When it creates the user successfully it redirects to `Index()`.

What I want is to **get redirected** when all is OK, but **stay in the current page** and see the error when something failed.

I'm using `jQuery ajax` with `MVC`.

My controller looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult CreateUser(string username)
{
    try
    {
        //here the logic to create the user
    }   
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string error = string.Format("Error creating user: {0}", ex.Message);
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        Response.Write(error);    
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The form submit is intercepted with jQuery, and then the call is made with ajax:

```
$("#new-user-form").submit(function() {
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            //At this point I would like to redirect
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $(".error-summary").html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });

    //cancel the event
    return false;
});
```

It works fine when an error occurs, but I don't know how to implement the success case.

I'm opened to other alternatives.

Comment: I have a similar situation. I have page containing a form to fill. A button on the page pulls data from one field, calls a web service to look up related data, and redirects to another page if the lookup was successful. I use Ajax to bypass data validation because the validated fields aren't applicable to the button's lookup operation. If the lookup fails, I want to display an error on the same page. At least that's what I would like it to do.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are going to redirect in the success action why are you using AJAX? The purpose of AJAX is to refresh only parts of a site without reloading the whole page. If in the success action you are going to redirect that totally defeats all the purpose and benefits you get from AJAX. But because you asked here's what you could do:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult CreateUser(string username)
{
    ...
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return Json(new { redirectToUrl = Url.Action("Index") });
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And then:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    window.location.href = data.redirectToUrl;
},
```

Comment: @Darin: I'm not sure if I understand the solution, please could you explan how it works exactly? Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel, in the controller action we check whether this request was an AJAX request (`Request.IsAjaxRequest`) and if yes we return a JSON object which looks like this: `{ redirectToUrl = '/home/index' }`. jQuery understands JSON and when it sees it it automatically parses it and passes it to the `data` parameter passed to the `success` callback. So now in the success callback you have access to `data.redirectToUrl` which is equal to `/home/index` and we use the `window.location.href` function to redirect the browser to this url. But as I explained in my post this is completely useless.

Comment: @Darin: I need to stay in the page if something failed. This is the reason I'm using AJAX. Is there other better way to do this?

Comment: @Darin : I'm not sure AJAX is useless -- he does not redirect on errors, so in that sense it does cut down on redirects if there are lots of errors.

Comment: @Daniel, the case when something goes wrong is not the typical use case. It is good to foresee it and take it into account but think of it as something exceptional, something which doesn't happen often or at least it shouldn't. If you think that there are going to be lots of errors you need to fix your code. So a better way is to use simple HTML form with simple input fields, which simply post to a simple controller action which attempts to do whatever it has to do and if it succeeds it redirects and if it fails you add errors to the model state and render the same view. Pretty basic stuff.

Comment: @Darin: Basically, the user can input a userName (it must be a existing user in the system). The userName texbox has autocomplete functionality but the user can always type a wrong user name by error. I this case I want to stay in the page and preserve the form values.

Comment: @Darin- Thanks for this suggestion- it worked perfectly for my MVC/Ajax-Form problem. Much Appreciated!

Comment: I agree with @Hogan. This solution is a good one, and I'm not sure why you feel it's an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative answer which uses pure MVC classes and you don't have to hardcode any script or use jQuery. First, I found the validators of MVC 2 work fine in success, failure and confirm cases as long as you remember:

1) Include necessary MVC scripts (three in total plus EnableClientSideValidation call - see MSDN).

2) Put MetadataClassAttribute and RequiredAttribtues on your model/data entities. You don't have to create separate metadata classes and make your model partial (I find that pants) just reference the same model class in the attribute.

3) Solve the AJAX redirect issue by returning JavaScript as already suggested (but in a jQuery orientated way)...

I only suffered strange behaviour during validation when it already failed to redirect from the list page to a details/edit page. The error messages would appear for a few seconds then disappear! Of course it was confused because the shell of the page was the first list page and the inner contents from the edit page. So the root cause of the problem was the out-the-box MVC 2 toolkit failing to redirect properly from the first page, not that the validators were not working properly on the second page.

I found the same solution here:

http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-ajax-redirect/
...which I expanded into an extension method and class in VB.NET:

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' MVC extension methods.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Module MvcExtensions

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Returns an <see cref="AjaxAwareRedirectResult"/> for the specified action
        ''' and optional controller name.
        ''' </summary>
        <Extension()> _
        Public Function AjaxAwareRedirectToAction(controller As Controller, _
                                         actionName As String, _
                                         Optional controllerName As String = Nothing) _
                                     As RedirectResult

            ' Get target URL
            Dim url = controller.Url.Action(actionName, controllerName)

            ' Return AJAX aware redirect result
            Return New AjaxAwareRedirectResult(url)

        End Function

   End Module

    ''' <summary>
    ''' <see cref="RedirectResult"/> which works with MVC 2 AJAX.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks>
    ''' Normal redirects do not work with AJAX partial updates in MVC (HTTP 302 status).
    ''' With MVC 2 AJAX it is necessary to return JavaScript to change the browser location.
    ''' </remarks>
    Public Class AjaxAwareRedirectResult
        Inherits RedirectResult

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Creates an instance which redirects to the specified URL using
        ''' a response containing either AJAX JavaScript or classic HTTPS 302 status.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="url">Target URL.</param>
        Sub New(url As String)
            MyBase.New(url)
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Generates the response.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Overrides Sub ExecuteResult(ByVal context As ControllerContext)

            ' Check if AJAX was used for request
            If context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest Then

                ' Perform JavaScript redirect when AJAX is used
                Dim destinationUrl As String = UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(Url, context.HttpContext)
                Dim result As JavaScriptResult = New JavaScriptResult With {
                        .Script = ("window.location='" + destinationUrl + "';")}
                result.ExecuteResult(context)

            Else

                ' Perform classic HTTP 302 status redirect
                MyBase.ExecuteResult(context)

            End If

        End Sub

    End Class
```

So then you have two options. You can follow the typical MVC pattern of calling AjaxAwareRedirectToAction(aciton, [controller]) for MVC targets, or return a new instance of an AjaxAwareRedirectResult(url) when you have a specific URL target in mind (i.e. external site).

I was really surprised that Microsoft didn't get AJAX redirects sorted in the first MVC 2 RTM. I have to use MVC 2 on my current project which is why I have to suffer this limitation, but also have some newer MVC solutions which I see are leaning more towards jQuery for validation. I will find out soon if they fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to redirect in the success action why are you using AJAX? The purpose of AJAX is to refresh only parts of a site without reloading the whole page. If in that any error or session expire you are going to redirect default login page.For that you have to override AuthorizeAttribute Filter so make class belew:

```
public class CheckAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["AFSUserId"] == null || !HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 302; //Found Redirection to another page. Here- login page. Check Layout ajaxError() script.
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl + "?ReturnUrl=" +
                filterContext.HttpContext.Server.UrlEncode(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl));
         }
     }
}
```

After Making that CheckAuthorization Class you have just put whenever you call ajax Authorization like below:

```
[CheckAuthorization]
public class BuyerController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet()]
    public ActionResult GetOrderlist()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

now you have to handle ajax status 302 in view side on each Ajax call
so put line of code in your layout page  order by leadid desc any particular page so like below:

```
    $(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
        if (jqXHR.status == 302) {
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Login", "Home")';
        }
    });
```

Here you are redirect to login page if current session expire or Timeout.

Answer (score 0):

```
 window.location.href="url here"
```

[Moz Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location)

Comment: @Daniel : The URL which you want to go to -- it seems @Darin solves this problem with ` Url.Action("Index")` -- is that where you want to go on success?